# I've got a problem Re-installing a clean Android Studio version - no add-ons

Tags: android, kotlin, installation, uninstallation

I'm trying to learn Kotlin and Android Studio, just to immerge myself in this new experience. A while ago I've installed Android Studio and I've put on some add-ons, without knowing what I was doing.

Now that I've followed the Kotlin instructions for learning the basics on the Android Website, I'm ready to step on the next level and try to apply this knowledge on the software to learn effectively with the tutorial steps. But I've figured it out that Android Studio was already full of many things that I didn't really know what they were needed for. So I tried to uninstall everything and wipeout and traces of Android studio from the pc, but I encounter the same problem, always.

[image: THIS. I DON'T KNOW WHAT IT IS. HOW TO DEFINE or SOLVE IT.]

I wish to re-install a clean version of Android Studio, learn the basics and understand which add-ons I should use later, when I have some basic knowledge of the system. I know I've made a mistake, but how can I solve this problem? I'm at the fourth re-installation.

Unistalled everything. Followed Many guides, even here on Stack Overflow. Can't find a way to solve this.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest version of Android Studio? code.google.com was closed years ago. Of course some where inside AS this error message may have survived the years, but more likely you are using an outdated version of AS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a 64 bit version of Windows 10 or 11. The CPU in your system should be an Intel or AMD CPU.

#### Uninstall and clean-up

You can delete the following folders that belong to Android Studio. Some of the mentioned folders are hidden by default. To get to the directory you can copy the folder name from this answer and paste it into the address bar of Windows explorer and press the return key.

1. Uninstall Android Studio via Windows control panel where it lists all installed applications
2. Delete the folder `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio`
3. Delete the folder `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android`
4. Delete all folders that start with `AndroidStudio` inside `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Google`
5. Delete all folders that start with `AndroidStudio` inside `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google`
6. If it exists also delete the folder `C:\Users\%username%\.gradle`
7. If it exists also delete the folder `C:\Users\%username%\.android` **Warning: this will delete existing APK signature keys, so don't do this if you have apps you need to sign with the same signature keys**.

## Reinstall

1. reboot your system
2. Download the latest version from https://developer.android.com/studio
3. Install the downloaded version of Android Studio

Comment: I've figured it out. Thanks. I've used those steps. What I was missing is some file somewhere (I don't remember where now). Now I've solved it. THanks a lot. I can freshly start to learn.

Comment: @ValerioPelling If my answer was helpful feel free up upvote and/or accept it. This works even with yor current reputation score as it is an answer to your own question.