i was unable to start my android studio and i have reinstalled it like 6 times already
Internal error. Please refer to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708
com.intellij.ide.plugins.EssentialPluginMissingException: Missing essential plugins: com.android.tools.design, org.jetbrains.android
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.checkEssentialPluginsAreAvailable(PluginManagerCore.kt:577)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.kt:644)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$initializeAndSetPlugins$2.invokeSuspend(PluginManagerCore.kt:830)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$initializeAndSetPlugins$2.invoke(PluginManagerCore.kt)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$initializeAndSetPlugins$2.invoke(PluginManagerCore.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:78)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.impl.TracerKt.span(tracer.kt:56)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main$startApp$2$1$1.span(Main.kt:92)
    at com.intellij.diagnostic.CoroutineTracerShim.span$default(CoroutineTracerShim.kt:31)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializeAndSetPlugins$intellij_platform_core_impl(PluginManagerCore.kt:829)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader$scheduleLoading$pluginSetDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(PluginDescriptorLoader.kt:377)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)


Your JRE: 17.0.11+0--11852314 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
i uninstalled and reinstalled the android studio still the same

what is your system configuration? And have you tried using Jetbrains toolbox https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/

Make sure that you manually uninstall everything not only the Android Studio main program. Some time ago I had listed the necessary paths in an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77461837/150978 BTW why do you use Intelli and IntelliJ-plugin tag but not Android-studio? The latter would make more sense and attract the right people.

Try to delete the disabled_plugins.txt file from the IDE configuration directory if it exists https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory It appears that some essential plugins were disabled

I don't think it is any issue try to uninstall all component of android studio clear the caches in c drive then install it again then it will work

i deleted the disabled_plugins.txt and it worked
